# F# List contains

Tags: list, recursion, f#, boolean, contains

I need help in F#. I need to verify if a number exist in the list, using a recursive function and without using `List.contains` or something similar. The program should only tell me if it's true or false. for example:

```
contains(8N, [3N; 8N; 2N]) = true
contains(7N, [3N; 8N; 2N]) = false
```

What I have until now:

```
let rec contains(x: Nat, list: Nat list): bool =
    match list with 
    | [] -> false
    | x::xs when x =
```

Comment: Please add the code you have so far.

Comment: Since this is homework, here's a hint rather than a complete answer. With F# lists, you often want to divide the list into the first item and the rest, then do some operation on the first item and call your function recursively on the rest of the list. Eventually the rest of the list will be empty, at which point you don't make any more recursive calls.

Comment: let rec contains(x: Nat, list: Nat list): bool =
    match list with 
    | [] -> false
    | m::xs when x =

Answer (score 4):

The code you have so far is a good starting point. I'll replace `Nat` with `int` which is the type name that F# uses and replace the tupled parameter with a space separated one, which is a more common notation.

One thing you need to do first is to avoid using the name `x` twice - right now, you have `x` as the name of the number you're looking for and as the name for the first element of the list. Once you rename them, you can specify the condition in `when`:

```
let rec contains (lookingFor:int) (list:int list) : bool =
    match list with 
    | [] -> false
    | firstInList::restOfList when firstInList = lookingFor -> (...)
    | firstInList::restOfList -> (...)
```

Now, there are two things you need to handle:

- When `firstInList = lookingFor`, you want to return `true`.
- Otherwise (the last case I added), you need to make the recursive call. You know that `firstInList` is not the number you're looking for and you need to check if `restOfList` contains the number - which is a single recursive call to your `contains` function.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is very simple: traverse a list and check whether its first element is equal to the one you are looking for. If it is, return true, otherwise move on to search the remainder of the list. If the (original or remainder) list is empty, no element satisfied the condition, and so the result is false.

This can be modeled very compactly as a small recursive function:

```
let rec contains n = function
    | [] -> false
    | x :: xs -> (n = x) || contains n xs
```

By the way, this function will not only work with lists of integers; it will be automatically generalized to work with lists of any type that supports an equality comparison.